# Make flutter app force a user to choose an account with FirebaseAuth and GoogleSignInAuthentication

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I want to force a user to select one of his account during login time. Is there any method to do so? I haven't found any configuration like `prompt=select_account+consent`.

Now, with these codes, after a user logout and then try to login again, it will automatically sign in with the selected account, there is no window showing up for user to select an account.

pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_auth: ^0.8.1+4
google_sign_in: ^3.2.4
```

Login part

```
GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
);
user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

Logout part

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
await _googleSignIn.signOut();
```

Comment: How many google accounts is registered in your phone?

Comment: I have 3 google accounts.

Comment: For me that code is working, so i don't think where the problem lies. Usually i build my main component using a StreamBuilder and the stream is the onAuthStateChanged and when i click the login button it shows a prompt of what to account to sign in.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use `GoogleSignInAccount.disconnect()` before signing out to revoke the previous authentication:

```
await _googleSignIn.disconnect();
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
```

Answer (score 5):

Harold's answer used to work for me, but recently the GoogleSignIn().currentUser appears null for some devices I tested, and then the disconnect function won't work. So, what solved that problem was ensuring it is signed in to Google.

```
final googleCurrentUser =
        GoogleSignIn().currentUser ?? await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
    if (googleCurrentUser != null)
      await GoogleSignIn().disconnect().catchError((e, stack) {
        FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(e, stack);
      });
    await _auth.signOut();
```

Comment: Use `GoogleSignIn().isSignedIn()` instead of checking for null and you don't need to force the signIn.

Answer (score 0):

GoogleSignIn().disconnect();  always requires that you restart the app and I wanted my app to work right after I logged out. So what worked for me was this:

```dart
class AuthenticationServices {
    final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    .
    .
    //    implement your sign-in methods here
    .
    .

    Future<void> logout() async {
        var isSignedIn = await _googleSignIn.isSignedIn();
        if (isSignedIn) await googleSignIn.signOut();
        _firebaseAuth.signOut();
    }
}
```

What is important here is that you use the same instances of the GoogleSignIn class for the sign-in and also the sign-out.

Hope this works :)

Answer (score -4):

A simple way to go about it :-
In your sign out method just use

```
_auth.signOut();
```

Now inside Google Sign In package, inside google_sign_in.dart

```
 Future<GoogleSignInAccount> signIn() {
    final Future<GoogleSignInAccount> result =
        _addMethodCall(GoogleSignInPlatform.instance.signIn, canSkipCall: false);
    bool isCanceled(dynamic error) =>
        error is PlatformException && error.code == kSignInCanceledError;
    return result.catchError((dynamic _) => null, test: isCanceled);
  }
```

Find the above method & set the canSkipCall parameter as false

```
final Future<GoogleSignInAccount> result =
        _addMethodCall(GoogleSignInPlatform.instance.signIn, canSkipCall: false);
```

This will enable choosing a user every time you try to sign in